# BackPressed via Fragment to previous Fragment-Navigation Component

Tags: android-architecture-navigation, onbackpressed, android-navigationview, child-fragment, android-navigation-graph

I want to ask:
From childFragment to the previous Fragment, BackPressed() is allowed while using Navigation Component, androidx, Kotlin.

What I was trying to code is to navigate fragments and bottomNavigation.
In one fragment, I used child fragments via customViewPager disabling swiping.
While coming back to childFragment, I want it to come the previous Fragment, not on parent/host.

Is it possible?
Is BackPressed() method applicable to use within fragments?